# Subsetting in R using multiple conditions (problems with NA values)

Tags: r, subset, na

Good morning everyone

I have a dataframe that has 4 columns.

I am trying to substract all observations that have a value X in column 1,  and have NA values in the other 3 columns.

Here is the code that I tried so far :

```
df <-
df[!(
df$col1 == "X" &
is.na(df$col2) &
is.na(df$col3) &
is.na(df$col4),]
```

The subsetting works, but it also creates observations with a new name (NA.1, NA.2, NA.3, etc.) that have missing values for all four columns.

I do not know why the first condition (`col1 == "X"`) is not respected, as the new `df` includes observations with a `NA` value in col1 instead of a required "X" value".

Would you have any idea why this is the case?

I included everything in the first step but will of course provide more details if necessary.

Comment: Check your parentheses - the `!(...` is not closed in your example. Otherwise, it is hard to tell what is going on without seeing your data.

Comment: Try `df[with(df, !col1 %in% 'X' & rowSums(is.na(cbind(col2, col3, col4)) == 0)), ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers and ideas.

The suggestion did not work but I searched from that and found a working solution :

```
df <-
  df[with(df, !(col1 %in% "X" &
                    is.na(col2) &
                    is.na(col3) &
                    is.na(col4)
  )), ]
```